# Configuring ScriptSharp to generate .js as embedded assembly resource in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, script#

I can't seem to understand how it works. 
I see there is an option **`/assembly`** available to the Script# compiler which procuces a .dll file with the .js file as a resource. Here is an example from http://www.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharpIntro.aspx:

`ssc /ref:sscorlib.dll /ref:Script.ScriptFX.Core.dll /debug /assembly:HelloWorld.dll /out:HelloWorld.js HelloWorld.cs`

Can I get the same result using Script# Visual Studio templates? How do I enable this option for my Script# project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to produce an assembly with script embedded in it.

I think the /assembly flag might be a remnant, or is there primarily for the script# compiler to know where the assembly produced from the same code as produced by the c# compiler exists.

If you want to embed the script in that assembly, you'll need to do a two pass c# build - in pass 1, there is a placeholder script, and then in pass 2, the real generated script.

Alternatively I can think of some approaches involving ildasm, add script resource reference, and then ilasm'ing to get back a new assembly.

What is your scenario? I am curious. I've debated whether to make the two pass build be supported out of the box... but never gotten around to it, since the embedding a script was a nice-to-have.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out. I was a bit confused how the /assembly flag is supposed to work. Yes, it would be great to produce the embedded script assembly , but that is not an important feature. This is just what I always did with my *.js files - I would embed them into a single nice assembly and reference them via `ScriptManager`.